# Rails 4 querying against postgresql column with array data type error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to query a table with a column with the postgresql array data type in Rails 4.

Here is the table schema:

```
create_table "db_of_exercises", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "preparation"
    t.text     "execution"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "body_part",      default: [], array: true
    t.hstore   "muscle_groups"
    t.string   "equipment_type", default: [], array: true
  end
```

The following query works:

```
SELECT * FROM db_of_exercises WHERE ('Arms') = ANY (body_part);
```

However, this query does not:

```
SELECT * FROM db_of_exercises WHERE ('Arms', 'Chest') = ANY (body_part);
```

It throws this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: record = character varying
```

This does not work for me either:

```
SELECT * FROM "db_of_exercises" WHERE "body_part" IN ('Arms', 'Chest');
```

That throws this error:

```
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

So, how do I query a column with an array data type **in ActiveRecord**??

What I have right now is:

```
@exercises = DbOfExercise.where(body_part: params[:body_parts])
```

I want to be able to query records that have more than one body_part associated with them, which was the whole point of using an array data type, so if someone could enlighten me on how to do this that would be awesome. I don't see it anywhere in the docs.

**Final solution for posterity:**

Using the overlap operator (&&):

```
SELECT * FROM db_of_exercises WHERE ARRAY['Arms', 'Chest'] && body_part;
```

I was getting this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] && character varying[]
```

so I typecasted ARRAY['Arms', 'Chest'] to varchar:

```
 SELECT * FROM db_of_exercises WHERE ARRAY['Arms', 'Chest']::varchar[] && body_part;
```

and that worked.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to write a detailed question, including your code, exact error messages, etc. It's good to always include your PostgreSQL version too (`SELECT version()`) though in this case it doesn't look like it matters much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that it has related to rails.

What if you do the follow?

```
SELECT * FROM db_of_exercises WHERE 'Arms' = ANY (body_part) OR 'Chest' = ANY (body_part)
```

I know that rails 4 supports Postgresql ARRAY datatype, but I'm not sure if ActiveRecord creates new methods for query the datatype. Maybe you can use `Array Overlap` I mean the **&&** operator and then doind something like:

```
WHERE ARRAY['Arms', 'Chest'] && body_part
```

or maybe give a look to this gem: https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/blob/master/docs/querying.md

And then do a query like:

DBOfExercise.where.overlap(:body_part => params[:body_parts])

Comment: Yes, that works, but I should have been more specific. Really I am looking for how to query using ActiveRecord, something like this: DbOfExercise.where(body_part: params[:body_parts]). I don't know ahead of time what values the user will select so using the OR statement does not seem feasible. I edited my question above.

Comment: Array overlaps is certainly what you want. `= ANY` makes no sense for a multiple value left hand side.

Comment: +1 for `postgres_ext`. Solves the problem of making the queries from Rails.

Answer (score 6):

@Aguardientico is absolutely right that what you want is the array overlaps operator `&&`. I'm following up with some more explanation, but would prefer you to accept that answer, not this one.

### Anonymous rows (records)

The construct `('item1', 'item2', ...)` is a *row-constructor* unless it appears in an `IN (...)` list. It creates an anonymous row, which PostgreSQL calls a "record". The error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: record = character varying
```

is because `('Arms', 'Chest')` is being interpreted as if it were `ROW('Arms', 'Chest')`, which produces a single `record` value:

```
craig=> SELECT ('Arms', 'Chest'), ROW('Arms', 'Chest'), pg_typeof(('Arms', 'Chest'));
     row      |     row      | pg_typeof 
--------------+--------------+-----------
 (Arms,Chest) | (Arms,Chest) | record
(1 row)
```

and PostgreSQL has no idea how it's supposed to compare that to a string.

I don't really like this behaviour; I'd prefer it if PostgreSQL required you to explicitly use a `ROW()` constructor when you want an anonymous row. I expect that the behaviour shown here exists to support `SET (col1,col2,col3) = (val1,val2,val3)` and other similar operations where a `ROW(...)` constructor wouldn't make as much sense.

### But the same thing with a single item works?

The reason the single `('Arms')` case works is because unless there's a comma it's just a single parenthesised value where the parentheses are redundant and may be ignored:

```
craig=> SELECT ('Arms'), ROW('Arms'), pg_typeof(('Arms')), pg_typeof(ROW('Arms'));
 ?column? |  row   | pg_typeof | pg_typeof 
----------+--------+-----------+-----------
 Arms     | (Arms) | unknown   | record
(1 row)
```

Don't be alarmed by the type `unknown`. It just means that it's a string literal that hasn't yet had a type applied:

```
craig=> SELECT pg_typeof('blah');
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 unknown
(1 row)
```

### Compare array to scalar

This:

```
SELECT * FROM "db_of_exercises" WHERE "body_part" IN ('Arms', 'Chest');
```

fails with:

```
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

because of implicit casting. The type of the `body_part` column is `text[]` (or `varchar[]`; same thing in PostgreSQL). You're comparing it for equality with the values in the `IN` clause, which are unknown-typed literals. The only valid equality operator for an array is `=` another array of the same type, so PostgreSQL figures that the values in the `IN` clause must also be arrays of `text[]` and tries to parse them as arrays.

Since they aren't written as array literals, like `{"FirstValue","SecondValue"}`, this parsing fails. Observe:

```
craig=> SELECT 'Arms'::text[];
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
LINE 1: SELECT 'Arms'::text[];
               ^
```

See?

It's easier to understand this once you see that `IN` is actually just a shorthand for `= ANY`. It's an *equality* comparison to each element in the `IN` list. That isn't what you want if you really want to find out if two arrays overlap.

So that's why you want to use the array overlaps operator `&&`.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Are text[] and varchar[] really the same thing though? I was getting an error and had to typecast the ARRAY['Arms', 'Chest'] to varchar when using the && operator against the body_part column (expanded on this in my question).

Comment: @kwyoung11 They're not *precisely* the same thing; `varchar(n)` carries a length constraint with it. They're implicitly castable to each other and in most places are equivalent, but there are a few places Pg isn't allowed to treat them as the same. They're the same in-memory and on-disk data type, it's just the length constraint that forces it to treat them slightly differently sometimes. I avoid `varchar` and just use `text` everywhere. If I want a length constraint I add an explicit `check` constraint. I find this clearer and more consistent, but then I don't have to write portable schemas.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I thought there might have been a performance difference, but according to the docs that isn't the case.